# GPSD cannot build the c++ lib

Tags: c#, c++, gpsd

I am trying to build a `C#` wrapper around the `C++` library from `GpsD` (`Gps Deamon`). My problem is now that I cannot get the library to build. I am not very good with libraries in `C++`.

I am using visual studio to build the project. I already fixed some issues but I am forgetting some files or something. I tried putting in the whole source but that makes even more errors.

Here are the errors I get:
[image: errors]

These errors doesn't make any sense to me.

This is also the code I have right now on github: [Github](https://github.com/Ghosttje/GPSD-Wrapper)

Is there somebody who can help me building this library, or does somebody have a version already builded?

Comment: Yea I also googled the error, but It is a library and normally libraries should work right away I think?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 'right away'. The linker needs the definitions of those functions. So you need to link with a library containing those functions, or add all it's source files in your C++ project (which, if you're lucky, might just work).